# url path fatal though shell list the file along dir?

Tags: git, unix

```
'
(base) $@ooooo overseries % git rm convergepi.c 
fatal: pathspec 'convergepi.c' did not match any files
(base) $@ooooo overseries % rm convergepi.c 
rm: convergepi.c: No such file or directory
(base) $@ooooo overseries % git status 
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   convergepi.c 
    modified:   piprox.c

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    a.out

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
(base) $@ooooo overseries %     
'
```

While trying to remove the old program the shell returns a fallacy that of each file url is not along dir? how else may I delete the old file?

Comment: try `git checkout -- convergepi.c `

Comment: What version of Git are you using, and did you configure `status.relativePaths` to `false`? If so, what directory are you in vs what directory does `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` show?

Comment: not the right one lol thanks